# Overuse of code snippet formatting

Tags: discussion, formatting

I often notice people using the `code snippet formatting` for many more things than showing code, often just to `emphasize` things.  And it can be quite `annoying` reading a `post` in which `every` other `word` is put in a `gray`, `monospace font` (see what I mean?).

Is there a way to encourage people to only use this formatting for what it is intended for?  As there are many **other**, more *appropriate ways* of ***emphasizing text***.

I have also seen it used for values, such as “I would use a density of `0.5`”, or “hit <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>`5`.  Are either of these appropriate?  At least for the latter example I would think that indicating a key press, regardless of whether it is a number, should always use the `<kbd>` tags.

Maybe I am being too nitpicky, but I do feel that this formatting has a specific purpose and is being quite overused.

Comment: I 100% agree. I try to edit these out and link to [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/251/599) whenever I seem them mis-used.

Comment: I agree as well. Note that in comments it is used to show a quote quite often. I personally think that is acceptable, but in questions/answers where the actual quote method is available, it is not acceptable.

Answer (score 11):

For values i think its reasonable,

eg: set the volume to `0.25`, blender's default texture path is `//textures`

but it shouldn't be used for emphasizing words alone.

Answer (score 7):

[ideasman42's](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/602/2217) answer is spot on.

I use the backtick formatting for any input value, short text or numeric, and short code snippets.
Example:
"type `180/pi` in to the Z axis rotation"  or
"a color vector is in the form of `[Red, Green, Blue, Alpha]`"

I think using backtick formatting to clearly format the input for a model operator is proper.
Example:
"Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> `5` to move the cube up 5 units on the Z axis."

The only place I use backtick formatting, when not directly formatting input is when the font does not clearly differentiate between <kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> (which is `<kbd>I</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd>` ). I sometimes use the backticks like this <kbd>`I`</kbd> (`` <kbd>`I`</kbd> ``) so the I is more clearly distinguishable.

I do agree that some times the backticks are over used, but I do not think that this is the worst problem facing BSE. A simple edit can fix any of these formatting `errors. :)`
However, all this only goes for questions and answers. Comments and chat posts, out of necessity need to use the backticks, because of the limited formatting options.

Answer (score 3):

I think this can definitively be over used, but, sometimes, there's no better way; How would you describe a *onscreen* button or list choice - you could use `<kbd>`, or *italics*, but that looks weird to me. So for instance, I would say "Check `Transparent` under the `Film` subsection.".

Comment: I believe that the general consensus is that italics should be used for menu items and on-screen buttons/categories.

Comment: Exactly ^^ Also for cascading buttons you can do i.e. *File > Save As*