# When to use italicization for keywords?

Tags: support

I'm curious and a bit confused on when to use italicization for keyword terms. I have noticed that [in this revision](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/269237/revisions) the italicization has been taken out for *Image Texture*. I have noticed that most reputable community members use italicization for keywords. I think *Image Texture* is a keyword that could potentially be italicized.

[image]

Comment: Italics here are used mainly for menus, UI items and other interface elements, as suggested in [those guidelines](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250/guidelines-on-the-usage-of-stackexchange-markup-and-style) and has [discussed recently a few posts ago](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2934/suggestion-for-new-node-name-formatting-guidelines)

Comment: hmmm i still see it quite often for other reputable members to use italicization for nodes [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/269256/red-circle-is-moving-along-path-with-location-pivot-as-p-and-scale-along-pivot/269273#269273) for example for the *Sample Curve* node

Comment: Have you read the post? That is one of the intended uses

Comment: yes a little, mostly skimmed through it. still gotta read the rest. but would be cool if it was consistent for all node type not just geometry nodes.

Comment: In my opinion, this should also be written as "image texture" since it does not refer to the node (at least not directly). Italics could be used for extra emphasis, but doesn't seem to be necessary here. Capitalizing would be fine if it is an "Image Texture node", since that is a proper noun in the context of Blender. That's nitpicking though.